# Stata: Save Regression Coefficients and Intercept for Panel Data

Tags: regression, stata, panel-data

I have a balanced Panel Data set and am trying to run the market model (i.e. E(R)=a+b*Rmkt). In order to do this, I need to run a regression for each day on the past 200 days.

So, I am looking for:

- how can I estimate the intercepts and slopes based on the past 200 trading days and for each firm individually? Basically, it needs to be estimated on the range of 200 days prior to the specific date.
- how can I save the intercepts and slopes for each observation?

I have already prepared the panel data:

```
list company companynum in 1/4114, sepby (company)
xtset companynum
xtset companynum date, daily
```

My Dataset looks like this:

```
input date companynum company return returnSP
end

     +------------------------------------------------+
     | date        companynum company return returnSP |
     |------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 3/21/2001    1          ESDI     0.04    0.65  |
  2. | 3/22/2001    1          ESDI     0.78    6.75  |
   . | ...          ...        ...       ...     ...  |
4115.| 3/21/2001    2          VWI     -0.065   0.65  |
4116.| 3/22/2001    2          VWI      1.6     6.75  |
     +------------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: SO isn't really for questions where you want us to write the code. Statalist is more appropriate for beginners.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. I tried it there ;)

Comment: Posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1398694-save-regression-coefficients-and-intercept-for-panel-data